# xsane does not work

Tags: scanner, 20.10

I'm using Ubuntu 20.10 and the network HP Printer HP_Color_LaserJet_MFP_M281fdw_5D71E8_
The pre installed driver to print works fine.
When I try to scan something with xsane i can select the scanner but when I try to scan it gives me the following error message :

> Failed to start scanner: Invalid argument

Comment: Say whether the device is connected by USB or not and give `scanimage -L`.

Comment: scanimage -L
device `escl:https://192.168.0.248:443' is a HP Color LaserJet MFP M281fdw (5D71E8) flatbed scanner

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Knowing whether you are USB-connected would still be useful to know.

The scanimage output indicates that only sane-escl is available. This is a driver provided by the SANE project and apparently it does not work with your M281fdw. The solution is to install sane-airscan:

`sudo apt install sane-airscan`

sane-airscan supports your device.